# reading UTF-16 produces unexpected results

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-16

I use the [beaglebuddy](http://www.beaglebuddy.com/) Java library in an Android project for reading/writing ID3 tags of mp3 files. I'm having an issue with reading the text that was previously written using the same library and could not find anything related in their docs.

Assume I write the following info:

```
MP3 mp3 = new MP3(pathToFile);
mp3.setLeadPerformer("Jon Skeet");
mp3.setTitle("A Million Rep");
mp3.save();
```

Looking at the source code of the library, I see that UTF-16 encoding is explicitly set, internally it calls

```
protected ID3v23Frame setV23Text(String text, FrameType frameType) {
   return this.setV23Text(Encoding.UTF_16, text, frameType);
}
```

and

```
protected ID3v23Frame setV23Text(Encoding encoding, String text, FrameType frameType) {
    ID3v23FrameBodyTextInformation frameBody = null;
    ID3v23Frame frame = this.getV23Frame(frameType);
    if(frame == null) {
        frame = this.addV23Frame(frameType);
    }

    frameBody = (ID3v23FrameBodyTextInformation)frame.getBody();
    frameBody.setEncoding(encoding);
    frameBody.setText(encoding == Encoding.UTF_16?Utility.getUTF16String(text):text);
    return frame;
}
```

At a later point, I read the data and it gives me some weird Chinese characters:

```
mp3.getLeadPerformer(); // 䄀 䴀椀氀氀椀漀渀 刀攀瀀
mp3.getTitle(); // 䨀漀渀 匀欀攀攀琀
```

I took a look at the built-in `Utility.getUTF16String(String)` method:

```
public static String getUTF16String(String string) {
    String text = string;
    byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(Encoding.UTF_16.getCharacterSet());
    if(bytes.length < 2 || bytes[0] != -2 || bytes[1] != -1) {
        byte[] bytez = new byte[bytes.length + 2];
        bytes[0] = -2;
        bytes[1] = -1;
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, bytez, 2, bytes.length);
        text = new String(bytez, Encoding.UTF_16.getCharacterSet());
    }

    return text;
}
```

I'm not quite getting the point of setting the first 2 bytes to -2 and -1 respectively, is this a pattern stating that the string is UTF-16 encoded?

However, I tried to explicitly call this method when reading the data, that seems to be readable, but always prepends some cryptic characters at the start:

```
Utility.getUTF16String(mp3.getLeadPerformer()); // ��Jon Skeet
Utility.getUTF16String(mp3.getTitle()); // ��A Million Rep
```

Since the count of those characters seems to be constant, I created a temporary workaround by simply cutting them off.

Fields like "comments" where the author does not explicitly enforce UTF-16 when writing are read without any issues.

I'm really curious about what's going on here and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The -1 and -2 are the Unicode byte order mark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark